# multiple timestamps in json body

Tags: json, curl, timestamp, iot, thingsboard

I'm trying to send time stamped key value pairs to the ThingsBoard Demo platform (demo.thingsboard.io). The standard way is to send a timestamp and with some key-value-pairs like so:

```
{"ts":1451649600512, "values":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}}
```

My problem is, that I need to process up to 100 acceleration measurements per second and I dont want to send a http post for every x-y-z value-package. Is there a way to send one json body with, lets say, 100 timestamps with corresponding measurements?

I tried it:

```
{
"ts": 1508695100,
"values": {
    "key1": 34,
    "key2": 26
},
"ts": 1508695200,
"values": {
    "key1": 38,
    "key2": 29
}
```

}

There is no error message when pushing this json to ThingsBoard with curl, but only the last timestamp-value-block seems to be recognized by ThingsBoard.

Any suggestions on how to to solve my problem?

Comment: ThingsBoards HTTP Api https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/#key-value-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use following format (json array):

`[{"ts":1451649600512, "values":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}}, {"ts":1451649600513, "values":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}}]`

or 

`[
    {
        "ts":1451649600512,
        "values":{
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2"
        }
    },
    {
        "ts":1451649600513,
        "values":{
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2"
        }
    }
]`

BTW, the JSON you have tried is not a valid JSON document at all. Please check the validity of the document before sending.

Comment: To improve the given answer.
My problem was, that I did not understand that I have to use the `"ts"` and `"values"` keys.

I sent the data without a `"values"` key and appended after the `"ts"` key directly my key value pairs.

So this is wrong and won't work:

    {
        "ts":1451649600513,
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2"
    }